# GDB shows incorrect jump address at PLT section

Tags: c, linux, assembly, gdb, shared-libraries

I wrote the following example to get a grasp of PLT/GOT section.

The shared library `libshar` code:

`shared.h`

```
int sum(int a, int b);
```

`shared.c`

```
#include "shared.h"

int sum(int a, int b){
    return a + b;
}
```

The executable `bin_shared` code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "shared.h"

int main(void){
    printf("Starting the programm... \n");
    int s = sum(1, 2); //<=== I expected the dynamic linker would be called here
    int s2 = sum(2, 3);
    printf("s = %d, s2 = %d\n", s, s2);
}
```

So I compiled and linked the shared library with the executable and wrote the following gdb-script to get into the dynamic linker code. I expected it to be executed on the first call to `sum`.

```
set pagination off

file build/bin_shared
b main
commands
    layout asm
    info proc mappings
end
r
```

I faced the 2 problems:

***I.*** When the breakpoint on the `main` function entry was hit the `info proc mappings` shows that `libshar.so` was already mapped:

```
0x7ffff7bd3000     0x7ffff7bd4000     0x1000        0x0 /home/me/c/build/libshar.so
0x7ffff7bd4000     0x7ffff7dd3000   0x1ff000     0x1000 /home/me/c/build/libshar.so
0x7ffff7dd3000     0x7ffff7dd4000     0x1000        0x0 /home/me/c/build/libshar.so
0x7ffff7dd4000     0x7ffff7dd5000     0x1000     0x1000 /home/me/c/build/libshar.so
```

**The `sum` shared library function had not been called yet. Why was it loaded eagerly already?**

***II.*** When entering the `sum@plt` for the first time I see the following asm:

```
0x555555554690 <sum@plt>   jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x200932]        # 0x555555754fc8
```

This is the pointer to the GOT as expected:

```
(gdb) disassemble 0x555555754fc8
Dump of assembler code for function _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_:
```

But the problem is that single instruction stepping at this point gets `gdb` right into the

```
0x7ffff7bd3580 <sum>            lea    eax,[rdi+rsi*1]
```

meaning that **the pointer to the GOT was already overwritten with the actual function pointer, but gdb still shows the GOT pointer. Why is that?**

I extracted the raw memory at the `jmp` to `GOT` address in hope of finding the overwritten address, but it does not seem like one:

```
(gdb) x/2xg 0x555555554690
0x555555554690 <sum@plt>:       0x01680020093225ff      0xffffffd0e9000000
```

Comment: Libraries are loaded at startup, not on demand. I can not reproduce your problem, the first time the step instruction takes me to the dynamic linker.

Comment: @Jester So libraries are just mapped into the memory, but jump address at `.plt` section is not resolved at that time. Is that correct?

Comment: @Jester _the first time the step instruction takes me to the dynamic linker_ Very strange. I tried even the very simple `hello world` example which shows `call   0x555555554540 <__printf_chk@plt>`. Single stepping `si` on this instruction gets control to the `0x7ffff7b161d0 <___printf_chk>` even though `0x555555554540 <__printf_chk@plt> jmp QWORD PTR [rip+0x200a8a]        # 0x555555754fd0` points to `_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_`

Comment: Maybe it's a gdb setting somewhere? Mine takes me to `_dl_runtime_resolve_xsavec () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/dl-trampoline.h:71`  GNU gdb (Debian 7.12-6) 7.12.0.20161007-git

Comment: @Jester Probably. I tried to set `b _dl_runtime_resolve_xsavec` before running the application and no breakpoints was hit.

Comment: Maybe you have `LD_BIND_NOW` set in the environment for some reason. Also you might try `set step-mode on` which should not really have any effect but who knows... You could also put a breakpoint (best a hardware one) right after the `jmp QWORD PTR [rip+0x200932]` which is where normally the entry points to (it should be a `push` and another `jmp`).

Comment: @Jester The problem turned out to be with gcc linker. I used a CMake project and it seems that it is required for gcc linker to add `-zlazy` flag. At least after setting it I also got to the `_dl_runtime_resolve_xsavec` on the first call. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why was it loaded eagerly already?

Because the dynamic loader `mmap`s *all* shared libraries that you directly link against.

If you want the shared library to be loaded on demand, you must use `dlopen` instead of linking the binary with `libshar.so`.

> the pointer to the GOT was already overwritten with the actual function pointer, but gdb still shows the GOT pointer. Why is that?

One of two likely causes:

1. You have `LD_BIND_NOW` set in the environment or
2. Your binary was linked with `-Wl,-z,now` (which could be the default on a newer Linux distribution).

You can examine whether 2 above is true with:

```
readelf -d bin_shared | grep FLAGS
```

For a `-z now` binary you would see:

```
  0x000000000000001e (FLAGS)              BIND_NOW
```