# How does dynamic linker know which library to search for a symbol?

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

I'm experimenting with `LD_PRELOAD`/`dlopen` and faced a confusion regarding symbol lookup. Consider the following 2 libraries:

1. `libshar`

`shared.h`

```
int sum(int a, int b);
```

`shared.c`

```
int sum(int a, int b){
    return a + b;
}
```

2. `libshar2`

`shared.h`

```
int sum(int a, int b);
```

`shared.c`

```
int sum(int a, int b){
    return a + b + 10000;
}
```

and executable `bin_shared`:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include "shared.h"

int main(void){
    void *handle = dlopen("/home/me/c/build/libshar2.so", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL);
    int s = sum(2 + 3);
    printf("s = %d", s);
}
```

linking the binary with `libshar` and `libdl` I considered the following 2 cases:

1. `LD_PRELOAD` is empty

The program prints `5`.

Why does the dynamic linker decide to lookup the `sum` function in the `libshar`, not `libshar2`? Both of them are loaded and contain the needed symbol:

```
0x7ffff73dc000     0x7ffff73dd000     0x1000        0x0 /home/me/c/build/libshar2.so
0x7ffff73dd000     0x7ffff75dc000   0x1ff000     0x1000 /home/me/c/build/libshar2.so
0x7ffff75dc000     0x7ffff75dd000     0x1000        0x0 /home/me/c/build/libshar2.so
0x7ffff75dd000     0x7ffff75de000     0x1000     0x1000 /home/me/c/build/libshar2.so
#...
0x7ffff7bd3000     0x7ffff7bd4000     0x1000        0x0 /home/me/c/build/libshar.so
0x7ffff7bd4000     0x7ffff7dd3000   0x1ff000     0x1000 /home/me/c/build/libshar.so
0x7ffff7dd3000     0x7ffff7dd4000     0x1000        0x0 /home/me/c/build/libshar.so
0x7ffff7dd4000     0x7ffff7dd5000     0x1000     0x1000 /home/me/c/build/libshar.so
```

2. `LD_PRELOAD = /path/to/libshar2.so`

The program prints `10005`. This is expected, but again I noticed that both `libshar.so` and `libshar2.so` are loaded:

```
0x7ffff79d1000     0x7ffff79d2000     0x1000        0x0 /home/me/c/build/libshar.so
0x7ffff79d2000     0x7ffff7bd1000   0x1ff000     0x1000 /home/me/c/build/libshar.so
0x7ffff7bd1000     0x7ffff7bd2000     0x1000        0x0 /home/me/c/build/libshar.so
0x7ffff7bd2000     0x7ffff7bd3000     0x1000     0x1000 /home/me/c/build/libshar.so
0x7ffff7bd3000     0x7ffff7bd4000     0x1000        0x0 /home/me/c/build/libshar2.so
0x7ffff7bd4000     0x7ffff7dd3000   0x1ff000     0x1000 /home/me/c/build/libshar2.so
0x7ffff7dd3000     0x7ffff7dd4000     0x1000        0x0 /home/me/c/build/libshar2.so
0x7ffff7dd4000     0x7ffff7dd5000     0x1000     0x1000 /home/me/c/build/libshar2.so
```

The `LD_PRELOAD` case seems to be explained in `ld.so(8)`:

> `LD_PRELOAD`
>
> A list of additional, user-specified, ELF shared objects to be loaded
>   before all others.  The items of the list can be separated by spaces
>   or colons.  **This can be used to selectively override functions in**
>   **other shared objects**.  The objects are searched for using the rules
>   given under DESCRIPTION.

Comment: The ELF standard dictates this.

Comment: @JL2210 How about some reference of quote?

Comment: Uh... Just lost my copy in a crash. Let me find a new one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dlopen` can't (nor can anything else) *change the definition* of (global) symbols already present at the time of the call. It can only make available new ones that did not exist before.

The (sloppy) formalization of this is in the [specification for `dlopen`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dlopen.html):

> Symbols introduced into the process image through calls to dlopen() may be used in relocation activities. Symbols so introduced may duplicate symbols already defined by the program or previous dlopen() operations. To resolve the ambiguities such a situation might present, the resolution of a symbol reference to symbol definition is based on a symbol resolution order. Two such resolution orders are defined: load order and dependency order. Load order establishes an ordering among symbol definitions, such that the first definition loaded (including definitions from the process image file and any dependent executable object files loaded with it) has priority over executable object files added later (by dlopen()). Load ordering is used in relocation processing. Dependency ordering uses a breadth-first order starting with a given executable object file, then all of its dependencies, then any dependents of those, iterating until all dependencies are satisfied. With the exception of the global symbol table handle obtained via a dlopen() operation with a null pointer as the file argument, dependency ordering is used by the dlsym() function. Load ordering is used in dlsym() operations upon the global symbol table handle.

Note that `LD_PRELOAD` is nonstandard functionality and thus not described here, but on implementations that offer it, `LD_PRELOAD` acts with load order after the main program but before any shared libraries loaded as dependencies.

Comment: The link you provided looks like a manual page for `dlopen`, but [this one](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) is different from what you quoted. On my machine I also did not find what you quoted in manuals. Is that an old version?

Comment: @SomeName: The link I quoted is the specification from the standard that defines `dlopen`, not the man page for a particular OS. The man pages are usually much less precise but also describe some implementation-specific behaviors outside the scope of the standard.

Comment: So the `Load order` mentioned in the quote is used for relocation processing. The relocation processing seems to be related to a dynamic symbol resolution when the dynamic linker is invoked on calling a function from PLT section for the first time. This would explain the case 1 I mentioned in the question...

Answer (score 5):

> Why does the dynamic linker decide to lookup the sum function in the libshar, not libshar2?

Dynamic linkers on UNIX attempt to emulate what *would have happened* if you linked with *archive* libraries.

In the case of empty `LD_PRELOAD`, the symbol search *order* is (when the symbol is referenced by the main binary; rules get more complicated when the symbol is referenced by the DSO): the main binary, directly linked DSOs in the order they are listed on the link line, `dlopen`ed DSOs in the order they were `dlopen`ed.

> `LD_PRELOAD = /path/to/libshar2.so`
>   The program prints 10005. This is expected,

Non-empty `LD_PRELOAD` modifies the search order by inserting any libraries listed after the main executable, and before any directly linked DSOs.

> but again I noticed that both libshar.so and libshar2.so are loaded:

Why is that a surprise? The dynamic linker loads all libraries listed in `LD_PRELOAD`, and then all libraries that you directly linked against (as [explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58014327/50617) before).

Comment: _rules get more complicated when the symbol is referenced by the DSO_ From what I got from the [spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dlopen.html) we have 2 symbol resolution orders: Load order and Dependency order. Which one is used for symbols that are referenced by DSOs?

Comment: Anyway, how did you discover this resolution order? The fact that the libraries are searched _in the order they listed on the link line_ is not specified in the spec I referred to (I tried it and it worked exactly as you described).